# How to preserve ALL website's URLS when transferring to a new CMS as well hosting

Tags: redirects, url, web-crawlers, url-rewriting, transfer

I am in a position where I have to figure out how to preserve all of the website's pages URLS  when transferring it to a new CMS, perhaps potentially Joomla (hasn't been decided yet). New hosting is also going to be required as well. It is extremely important that all of the URLs all pages stay preserved.

- How do I ensure the success of preserving the URLs?
- How do I transfer all the content in a non-technical way?
- Not sure if formerly 'Vision Internet' keeps the site static or non-static? How do I determine this?

Any friendly CMS recommendations that's not Wordpress (too hackable and bloated) or Drupal (too overly technical)?

Any further advice or tips would be super appreciated! Also would appreciate any other issues or thoughts not mentioned in this post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve all URLs from your current website to new website, you can create the URLs in your new website.

- **Preserving URLs:** Technically, in terms of SEO, as long as the URL structure is the same, your URLs are always preserved independent of the platform they are in (unless you make a big variation in content, it will not affect your current rankings).
- **Transfer content in non-technical way:** Recreate the pages with the same content from your previous website.
- **Regarding Static/Non Static Website:** You will have to check with your developers.

Suggestions:

> 1. When moving to a new platform or doing things right, preserving URLs totally depends on which type of pages you want to retain.
> 2. If your current URLs are ranking in any search engine, it is recommended that you do not change the URL structure and try to replicate the old page before initiating additional fixes or changes.
> 3. Regarding suggestions for CMS, can suggest you Joomla or Drupal if you do not prefer Wordpress. However, suggesting one totally depends on the website, its functionalities and integrations.

Comment: The Joomla url structure generally follows the menu and sub-menu structure once you have enabled search engine friendly urls and url rewriting. Joomla also has a built in Redirect Component which makes it easy to redirect old urls to new urls where necessary so search engines are happy.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awkward change by the sounds of it, best of luck.

As idk stated you can create the site with the same structure as the old site, making sure the urls remain the same. Any pages that cause a difficulty - I think using 301 redirects could fix the pages that are not able to be preserved.

You most likely cannot just copy it over and hope for the best, unfortunately.

I would suggest to whoever I was building this for to build the new site with new clean code, improve the site structure, use a tool such as SEMRush to build an optimised site, implementing microdata, submit a new sitemap. * build a site that scores higher than the last version, patiently wait for google to crawl the new one / request google to re-crawl...

Also, don't underestimate WordPress. You can use a security plug-in, purchase a server and some security measures through there too. WordPress is what you make of it (just like any CMS). Magento has always been my go to for more technical sites.